# xmodmap: where are its local settings stored?

Tags: xmodmap

I ran

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Menu = Super_L"
```

and could reverse it using

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = Menu"
```

But I want to know where changes made by running these particular commands are stored. I don't have `~/.xmodmaprc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can store them manually in `~/.Xmodmap`, then execute them with

```
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Only place the parts between the quotes in the file, that is `keycode 135 = Menu`, for example.